# Phantom - RPC Error: Something went wrong -32603

Tags: web3.js, phantom

I try to sign a text and I get this error.

```
const anchorWallet = useAnchorWallet();

const MEMO_PROGRAM_ADDRESS = "MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr";
const MEMO_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(MEMO_PROGRAM_ADDRESS);

const onTestSign = async () => {
   if (!anchorWallet) return;

   const tx = new Transaction();
   tx.add(
      new TransactionInstruction({
         programId: MEMO_PROGRAM_ID,
         keys: [],
         data: Buffer.from("hello world", "utf8"),
      })
   );

   tx.feePayer = anchorWallet.publicKey;
   tx.recentBlockhash = Keypair.generate().publicKey.toString();

   await anchorWallet.signTransaction(tx);
};
```

[image: Error]

**Again Above code works well on localhost, but when I test on the live server I got the above error.**

Live: [https://solana-web2-auth.vercel.app/](https://solana-web2-auth.vercel.app)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not grabbing a valid blockhash:

```
tx.recentBlockhash = Keypair.generate().publicKey.toString();
```

Try replacing it with a recent [blockhash](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#recent-blockhash):

```
let latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');
tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
```

Comment: this solution does not work. why should i use blockhash? the transaction is not sent to the chain.. Also the codes work very well on localhost.

Comment: @tolgaandx why are you using a transaction if you don't want it to go on the chain?